# Is $\mathbb R^2$ a vector space with the given scalar Multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Define Scalar Multiplication := $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^2 \to  \mathbb R^2$ where $c.(x,y)$ is the point rotated $c$ radians counter clockwise about the origin. Use the standard addition law on $\mathbb R^2$

Is $\mathbb R^2$ a vectorspace with this this definition of scalar MUltiplication ?

I think it is not a Vector Space with the definition of given Scalar MUltiplication because $\mathbb R$ is not closed under addition.

$c+d $ is equivalent to $\begin{bmatrix} \cos c+ \cos d & -\sin c-\sin d \\ \sin c + \sin d & \cos c + \cos d \end{bmatrix}$ which may not be a rotation matrix .

So $\mathbb R$ will not be a field .

Answer (score 3):

You have the rudiments of an idea that will work, but the way you're *presenting* this idea makes it into nonsense.

Let's define a symbol for the proposed scalar multiplication:
$$ c \star (x,y) = (x,y)\text{ rotated counterclockwise by }c\text{ radians} $$

What you're doing in the question looks like you're checking whether the left-distributive law
$$ (c+d)\star v = (c\star v) + (d\star v)$$
holds, as it must to for a scalar multiplication. You have then correctly computed the *right-hand side* of the law as
$$ (c \star (x,y)) + (d\star (x,y)) =
\begin{bmatrix} \cos c + \cos d & -\sin c - \sin d \\
\sin c + \sin d & \cos c + \cos d \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} $$
What you're missing is to compute the *left-hand side* similarly, giving
$$ (c+d)\star (x,y) =
\begin{bmatrix} \cos(c + d) & -\sin (c+d) \\
\sin(c + d) & \cos(c + d) \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} $$
When you do that you can observe that the left-hand side and right-hand side are not equal (by providing some concrete numbers for $c,d,x,y$ where you can see they evaluate to different things). Then you'll have a valid proof of the fact that $\star$ is not the scalar multiplication of a real vector space.

However, when you describe this as

> because $\mathbb R$ is not closed under addition.

this idea gets distorted almost beyond recognition. It sounds like you want to define a new addition operation on the reals which might make the distributive law work for $\star$ -- but that is not what the exercise asks you to do. $\mathbb R$ is what it is; addition of real numbers is what it *already* is, and that always produces a real number no matter which $\star$ or other functions you define to operate *on* the real numbers.

True enough, the problem statement doesn't explicitly *say* "use the standard addition on $\mathbb R$" -- but that must be because the author had not even imagined that you would understand the exercise as being about choosing a new addition.

$\mathbb R$ is a perfectly good field already, and using them to define something that turns out not to be a vector space will not change that.

The problem with $\star$ is just that it *doesn't satisfy the axioms* that have been defined for something to be a "scalar multiplication".

---

Shahab's answer points out that you could *also* have reached the conclusion that $\star$ is not a scalar multiplication by checking a *different* axiom instead of the one you did, namely $1\star v = v$. That way also works.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement that $1\cdot (x,y)=(x,y)$ is clearly not being met. So the given structure is not a vector space.

Comment: I think here $0$  would have been Unit element if it was a field. @Shahab

Comment: R is a field under standard addition and multiplication (this isn't mentioned explicitly but I am fairly confident that this is what the questionner is assuming) and the number $1$ is its multiplicative identity.

Comment: How would you define $c+d$ ?what will happen when $c+d$ will be operated on a vector ? will $c+d$ remain a Rotation Matrix ?@Shahab

Comment: You seem to be confused regarding the definitions. Here R is the field of real numbers with standard addition and multiplication. The purported vector space consists of $\mathbb R^2$ over $\mathbb R$ where vector addition is $(x,y)+(x',y')=(x+x',y+y')$ and scalar multiplication is $c\cdot (x,y)=(x\cos c-y\sin c, x\sin c+y\cos c)$. As explained in the answer, this is not actually a vector space.

Comment: You are not understanding my point. $\mathbb R$ has to be a field , but $\mathbb R$  is not a field here, @Sahab

Comment: Here the field $\mathbb R$ has been defined differently. $c+d $ is addition of two rotation matrices and $c+d$ is not just addition of two real numbers $c , d$ .@Shahab

Comment: I dont think the definition of addition provided is for R. R is the symbol for the set of real numbers and not of the set of rotation matrices. The definition of addition that is provided is for R^2 and is what I explained above.

Comment: You have messed up everything. I have written it on my own to show my attempt.@Shahabe

Comment: @sani why are you associating the addition of two real numbers as a $2\times 2$ matrix? The binary operation of addition on $\mathbb{R}$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$, not into $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling: It looks like he understood the exercise to mean, "determine whether there exists an alternative field structure on the set $\mathbb R$ such that the given operation becomes the scalar multiplication of a vector space".

Comment: @Troposphere any field structure on $\mathbb{R}$ requires a binary operation of "addition" on $\mathbb{R}$ whose codomain is $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$

Comment: @MatthewPilling: Right. So the OP is _also_ being sloppy about distinguishing between elements of $\mathbb R$ and the matrices that represent their action under the proposed "scalar multiplication". Nonetheless I think his comments make most sense if we assume that's how he's thinking.

Comment: @Troposphere It appears more to be case that the OP misinterpreted this alternate notion of "scalar multiplication" as a new binary operation on $\mathbb{R}$. All of this is cleared up in your fantastic answer. Great post!